# GUI for plotting data from 3D cell matricies in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a matlab cell matrix in which each cell contains a vector of numbers. I am trying to visualize the cell matrix data and plot various rows with various columns. However, I am still not sure which rows/columns should I pick and whether I should take the average, max or first/second/third.. value from each cell to get the desired output I am looking for. 
As I continuously change my plotting parameters, it gets really annoying to change multiple loops and their limits every time I want to try another plot. Trying to extract the correct information you want from a such a jungle becomes really frustrating.

[image: Screenshot of the cell matrix]

I am looking for a software/toolbox/GUI to help me play around and visualize this 3D cell matrix so I can plot whatever I need by some simple clicks and avoid the confusion of several loops inside each other.

Would there be any idea to help me through that?